# Trick question about FD's?

Tags: database-design, normalization, dependencies

```
X  Y  Z
x1 y1 z1
x1 y1 z1
x1 y1 z2
x2 y1 z1
```

The questions  are :

a. List all the non-trivial original functional dependencies that this relation instance preserves

b. Change a single value to eliminate all FDs that the above instance preserves.

---

To confirm that there is no typo from my part (could be from the professor):

[image: q3]

Comment: The sample has 2 identical rows. That shouldn't happen. (is it a typo or intentional?)

Comment: Nope no typo on my end. I think my prof may have messed this question up.  X, Y, Z are  the columns while x1, y1, z1, z2, x2 are the values in the schema. Uploaded full question from the document as a image.

Answer (score 2):

I see several non trivial dependencies (9 if I count right!)

How to find them: Since, the relation has few attributes, we can examine each possible dependency separately, taking the respective projection. (The possible dependencies with just 3 attributes are not very few. They are 64 but see below for some ways to make that number smaller.)

Example: `X -> Y`. Does `Y` depend on `X`? Yes.

```
X  Y
x1 y1
x2 y1
```

Example: `Y -> X`. Does `X` depend on `Y`? No.

```
Y  X  
y1 x1 
y1 x2
```

Example: `XY -> Z`. Does `Z` depend on `XY`? No.

```
X  Y  Z
x1 y1 z1
x1 y1 z2
x2 y1 z1
```

Also we don't have to examine them all (64 possible dependencies).

First, we need to examine only the (37) non-trivial ones. The `XY -> X` for example is trivial and of course holds, We don't have to examine the (27) trivial dependencies at all.

Second, we can deduce several ones, in both directions:

Once we find that `X -> Y` holds, we can deduce that `XZ -> Y` holds, too.
Once we find that `XY -> Z` does not hold, we can deduce that `X -> Z` and `Y -> Z` don't either.
We can also use Armstrong's axions to make further deductions.

I won't go on further details but I think the exercise is good - and tricky.

If you are observant enough, you only need to find a single dependency and then you can prove the rest (8) that hold, using these deductions.

And only find that 2 more dependencies do not hold and then you could prove that the above 9 are the only ones and no other holds.